# How to change null to default image path json and react js

Tags: reactjs

Hi everyone im trying to figure out how to display a default image for every beer thats in my db , its currently stated as null and trying to change it to another path need help

```
 fetch(urlBiere)
    // Récupération de la réponse en format JSON data des bieres 
        .then((response) => {return response.json() })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('URLBIERE');
            //console.log(data.data);
            setBiere(data.data);

            let bieres = data.data;
            //console.log(bieres);
            console.log(bieres.image);
            

            for (let i = 0, l = bieres.length; i < l ; i++) {
                //If null change to biero-bouteil.jpeg
            if(!bieres[i].image) bieres[i].image = '../assets/img/biero-bouteil.svg';
            console.log(bieres[i].image);                 
            }
            
        })
```

Comment: what's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import defaultImage from '../assets/img/biero-bouteil.svg';

render(){
 return (
  bieres.map(item => ( <img src="{item.image || defaultImage}" />))
 );
}
```

Comment: not sure itll work I need to loop through all the items and put img ... didnt work on my side